# Contact sorting in ICS? (Galaxy S alpha version)

Tags: contacts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I can't seem to find the sorting options in the contact list. Currently, the contacts are sorted by first name and displayed as "firstname lastname". I'd like to change it to be sorted by last name and displayed as "lastname, firstname", but the option seems to be missing.

Is this really the case in ICS or just the teamhacksung's alpha version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something like:

> People app -> press the menu button bottom right (the 3 vertical dots) -> settings -> Sort list by

Comment: Yep, there it was (except that the menu button is the physical button on my device). How did I miss that? Thanks!